# ArgumentError: Error #2015: Invalid BitmapData. on iOS

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, ipad, air, bitmapdata

The simplest graffiti app. The code works fine on the desktop and on Android. If i try to do the same on iOS (tested on a real device - iPad 2), i get this error: ArgumentError: Error # 2015: Invalid BitmapData.

In principle, it is clear why the error - the size of BitmapData is the huge.

Why it happens? And why only on iOS?

```
private var maskLine:Sprite = new Sprite();
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,onMove);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,onDown);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,onUp);

protected function onDown(ev:MouseEvent):void {
maskLine.graphics.lineStyle(20, 0x33CC00, 1);
maskLine.graphics.moveTo(mouseX, mouseY);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMove);
}
protected function onUp(ev:MouseEvent):void {
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMove);
}

protected function onMove(ev:MouseEvent):void {
    maskLine.graphics.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
}
```

Save in bitmap code:

```
        maskLine.filters = [new BlurFilter(4, 4, 1)];
        trace (Capabilities.screenResolutionX + '   ' + Capabilities.screenResolutionY + '  ' + maskLine.width + '   ' + maskLine.height);
    //768    1024    107374182.35    107374182.35
// Here is get error
        var bmpd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(maskLine.width, maskLine.height, true, 0x000000);
        bmpd.draw(maskLine);
```

Comment: Not necessarily. I usually get this error when one of the parameters `width` or `height` is not a positive Number (i.e. a negative Number, 0 or `NaN`).

Comment: Check out the BitmapData constructor reference - you might find your reason there: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#BitmapData()

Comment: @weltraumpirat You can see trace - maskLine.width == 107374182.35

Comment: if i set  new BitmapData(300, 300, true, 0x000000); then i get in console text: IDS_CONSOLE_WARN_FILTER_TOO_BIG

Comment: Did you comment out the blur?

Comment: @The_asMan, I checked - it does not help, of course. I do not know what the reason, but my sprite maskLine to get huge. Because of this error.

Comment: I search 107374182.35 and find it http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?16877-Flash-Limits/page6 So I do not understand why the sprite is stretched to the maximum width and height.

Comment: read this http://blog.yoz.sk/2010/10/quick-tip-stage-mousex-on-androi/

Comment: @The_asMan, Wow! It`s work! Many thanks! Could you put this as the correct answer!

Comment: I also used 'this' instead 'stage'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As requested here is the answer.](http://blog.yoz.sk/2010/10/quick-tip-stage-mousex-on-androi/)